# Promisifying the Stripe API

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, stripe-payments, es6-promise

I'm trying to `util.promisify` the following stripe call which does succeed:

```
stripe.customers.create(
  {
    description: 'My First Test Customer (created for API docs)',
  },
  function(err, customer) {
      console.log(customer)
  }
)
```

IIUC this should work:

```
const util = require('util')

const createCustomerPromise = util.promisify(stripe.customers.create)

createCustomerPromise(
{
    description: 'My First Test Customer (created for API docs)'
}
).then(customer=>console.log(customer))
```

However when I run the above I get:

```
(node:28136) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'createResourcePathWithSymbols' of undefined
    at /home/ole/Temp/stripetest/node_modules/stripe/lib/StripeMethod.js:27:12
    at internal/util.js:286:30
```

Comment: The Stripe SDK already returns Promises. Just omit the callback, i.e `stripe.customers.create().then().catch()`

Comment: @NikKyriakides - Given the title of the question is *"Promisifying the Stripe API"* (specifically), I'd say that qualifies as an *answer*. I'd post it as one (with the relevant doc link).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`create` seems to want `this` to be `stripe.customers` when it's called, so you'll need to `bind` it:

```
const createCustomerPromise = util.promisify(stripe.customers.create.bind(stripe.customers))
// −−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

If that's coming up a lot, you might give yourself a utility function:

```
function promisifyMethod(obj, name) {
    return util.promisify(obj[name].bind(obj));
}
```

Then

```
const createCustomerPromise = promisifyMethod(stripe.customers, "create");
```

---

But note that [Nik Kyriakides says the Stripe API already supports promises](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60100841/157247).

Answer (score 5):

Stripe's Node SDK, [`stripe-node`](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-node), already returns Promises so **you don't need to promisify it**.

From [the docs](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-node#using-promises):

> Every method returns a chainable promise which can be used instead of a regular callback:

Just omit the [error-first callback](http://fredkschott.com/post/2014/03/understanding-error-first-callbacks-in-node-js/):

```
stripe.customers.create({
  description: 'My First Test Customer (created for API docs)'
})
.then(result => console.log(result))
```

or using [`async/await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function):

```
const result = await stripe.customers.create({
  description: 'My First Test Customer (created for API docs)'
})
console.log(result)
```